# CSS Grid: Second Grid inside 100% height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, css-grid

I've got CSS Grid that shows some layout

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
   "tb tb"
   "lb cn";
 }

.lb {
  grid-area: lb;
  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
}

.tb {
  grid-area: tb;
  background: blue;
}

.cn {
   grid-area: cn;
   background: silver;
    overflow: auto;
}

.subgrid {
}

.header {
  height: 150px;
  background: yellow;

}

.content {

}
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="lb">LEFT BAR Lorem ipsum dolor sigiT BAR Lorem ipsum dolor sigiat voluptate, quasi pariatur ad dignissimT BAR Lorem ipsum dolor sigiat voluptate, quasi pariatur ad dignissimT BAR Lorem ipsum dolor sigiat voluptate, quasi pariatur ad dignissimT BAR Lorem ipsum dolor sigiat voluptate, quasi pariatur ad dignissimT BAR Lorem ipsum dolor sigiat voluptate, quasi pariatur ad dignissimat voluptate, quasi pariatur ad dignissimos.</div>
      <div class="tb">TOB BAR</div>
      <div class="cn">
        <div class="subgrid">
              <div class="header">HEADER</div>
              <div class="content">  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi voluptatum, sed, eos nulla, dignissimos alias ipsum id quasi vero veritatis blanditiis. Repudiandae quisnissimos alias ipsum id quasi vero veritatis blanditiis. Repudiandae qunissimos alias ipsum id quasi vero veritatis blanditiis. Repudiandae qu at s blanditiis. Repudiandae qunissimos alias ipsum id quasi vero veritatis blanditiis. Repudiandae qu at ipsam soluta recusandae alias quas labore a, fugiat eius sed, nostrum nulla. m ut facilis fugit, quam amet nobis quos consectetur excepturi numquam omnis.</div>
         </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Example 1

[image: EXAMPLE 01]

And it looks good because 'subgrid' shows scrollbar. But I want to make one change. I want to move scrollbar inside 'subgrid' (this will be another control el 'el-tab' from element-ui)

[image: ELEMENT UI]

so 'content' should fill the 'subgrid' with left space from the control but I cannot make this with parameter "height: 100%" or "height: 100vh", because in CSS GRID this parameters doesn't work properly :(

**height: 100%;**: it doesn't fill correct parent control with height: 300px;

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
   "tb tb"
   "lb cn";
 }

.lb {
  grid-area: lb;
  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
}

.tb {
  grid-area: tb;
  background: blue;
}

.cn {
   grid-area: cn;
   background: silver;

}

.subgrid {
}

.header {
  height: 150px;
  background: yellow;

}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="lb">LEFT BAR Lorem ipsum dolor sigiT BAR Lorem ipsum dolor sigiat voluptate, quasi pariatur ad dignissimT BAR Lorem ipsum dolor sigiat voluptate, quasi pariatur ad dignissimT BAR Lorem ipsum dolor sigiat voluptate, quasi pariatur ad dignissimT BAR Lorem ipsum dolor sigiat voluptate, quasi pariatur ad dignissimT BAR Lorem ipsum dolor sigiat voluptate, quasi pariatur ad dignissimat voluptate, quasi pariatur ad dignissimos.</div>
      <div class="tb">TOB BAR</div>
      <div class="cn">
        <div class="subgrid">
              <div class="header">HEADER</div>
              <div class="content">  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi voluptatum, sed, eos nulla, dignissimos alias ipsum id quasi vero veritatis blanditiis. Repudiandae quisnissimos alias ipsum id quasi vero veritatis blanditiis. Repudiandae qunissimos alias ipsum id quasi vero veritatis blanditiis. Repudiandae qu at s blanditiis. Repudiandae qunissimos alias ipsum id quasi vero veritatis blanditiis. Repudiandae qu at ipsam soluta recusandae alias quas labore a, fugiat eius sed, nostrum nulla. m ut facilis fugit, quam amet nobis quos consectetur excepturi numquam omnis.</div>
         </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Example 2

[image: EXAMPLE 02]

Is there any option to fill content from the inner  and set full Height without putting everything in one master GRID. I try options with display: subgrid or inline-grid , flex or bootstrap row,col but nothing helps :(. I can setup only when I set up whole layout in one grid like in the example below.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
   "tb tb"
   "lb header"
   "lb content";
 }

.lb {
  grid-area: lb;
  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
}

.tb {
  grid-area: tb;
  background: blue;
}

.cn {
   grid-area: cn;

}


.header {
  grid-area: header;
  height: 150px;
  background: yellow;

}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  overflow: auto;
   background: silver;
}
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="lb">LEFT BAR Lorem ipsum dolor sigiat voluptate, quasi pariatur ad di voluptatum, sed, eos nulla, dignissimos alias ipsum id quasi vero veritatis blanditiis. Repudiandae quis at ipsam soluta recusandae alias quas labore a, fugiat eius sed, nostrum nulla. m ut facilis fugit, quam amet nobis quos consectetur exceptignissimos.</div>
      <div class="tb">TOB BAR</div>
      <div class="header">HEADER</div>
      <div class="content">  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi voluptatum, sed, eos nulla, dignissimos alias ipsum id quasi vero veritatis blanditiis. Repudiandae quis at ipsam soluta recusandae alias quas labore a, fugiat eius sed, nostrum nulla. m ut facilis fugit, quam amet nobis quos consectetur excepturi numquam omnis.</div>


    </div>
```

Grid Total Layout

[image: GRID TOTAL LAYOUT]

Comment: I want 'content' to shrink to the available size by the parent grid, because some controls like 'el-tab-pane' shows me the content that could be big but they are not in the part of the grid layout, they are inside the control 'el-tabs'.

Comment: _el-tab-pane_  ,  _el-tabs_  ?! I guess that's where i get lost, what is this about ?